# Can I hide certain content on next page based on whether a dropdown option was selected on previous page?

Tags: php

This form calculates the pricing and gives a quote on the following page. (It's OK to submit the form to view the following page; it's not going anywhere yet). http://customwovenlabels.com/quote-woven-test.php

So, fill out the form and select  peel and stick backing as an example. On the redirect page, you will see a sentence under the first pricing table that says:
"A 30.00 charge for peel and stick backing has been added to the total price. "
Called up like this: A  charge for  backing has been added to the total price.

Is there a way to only show that sentence if a backing has been selected and hide it if it has not been? Over 90% of customers won't select a backing, so it's really better if it doesn't show up by default.

Answer (score 0):

As the value of iron-on and peel and stick are the same you cannot rely on the posted value of flatRateAdd.  What you can do is in yur js function calculateCost is get the text of the selected option for flatRateAdd and pass that to a hidden field which you can then read and compare in your woven-labels-order.php file when deciding wether to output that text or not.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this worked.

```
    <?php
     if (strpos($_POST[backingText],'none') !== false) {
     echo "There was no backing listed";
    }
    else {
    echo "A $_POST[backing] charge for $_POST[backingText] backing has been  added to the total price.";
}
?>
```